# Logs all queries fired from phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to create logs for all those queries which are fired from phpmyadmin. With queries I want to append username who fired the query. 
Is it possible to create logs only for phpMyadmin ?

Answer (score 1):

You have the **phpmyadmin.pma_history** table with **username, date, query** etc

[image: pma_history table]

Comment: i didn't get , where is it, can you share a screenshot ?

Comment: Maybe it's different with version of phpmyadmin. Don't select any database and look for Binary Log tab . You can select different logs from a drop down list and press GO Button to view them.

Comment: i am using phpmyadmin V3.5.8.1

Comment: Try `SELECT * FROM phpmyadmin.pma_history`

Comment: Table `pma_history` is part of the phpMyAdmin configuration storage and here is how you set it up. http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/QA_4_0/setup.html#phpmyadmin-configuration-storage

Comment: Not a wrong answer, but I think the MySQL binary log is of limited use because it only shows queries that modify data rather than all queries (for instance, SELECT statements aren't logged). It does have the benefit of logging queries from all sources, though, both from your applications and from within phpMyAdmin. The recent history feature doesn't seem a good fit; only certain queries are recorded, and it really wasn't designed to use in this way. I think Marc's reference to the tracking feature is really the ideal solution here.

Answer (score 1):

phpMyAdmin has the Tracking feature, that will log the queries done via its interface. Details on http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html?highlight=tracking#cfg_Servers_tracking.